# Mesh requirements for Mantaflow effector?

Tags: mesh, physics, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm having trouble being able to make a mesh to use as an effector with a fluid simulation. No matter the shape I make (cylinder, cube or sphere with the top off and a solidify modifier applied to it), the fluid seems to, in one way or another, go through it.

All transformations were applied and normals were recalculated so, I'm wondering: what are the requirements for a mesh that will act as a receptacle (like a cup or a bucket), in order for it to actually act as an effector?

Does it need to maybe have a certain thickness (maybe in relation to the voxel size?), do its faces all need to be quads, or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe you "just" added the effector object. But Mantaflow does not recalculate your simulation because of this. To force a recalculation, just change e.g. your resolution by 1. This should help. If this doesn't help, please provide a simple example blend file and we will check it out.

Comment: That only works in Replay mode.  In Modular, or All, you need to free the bake and redo it.

Comment: you are right. Just for replay. But because of his "trouble" i assumed he is a beginner and didn't change that.

Comment: Hey @Chris, I made a quick blender file [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cRmFlRi8KNOXx6Wa0lThOmUt0phSc_Id/view?usp=sharing) - I'm facing the same issue here, where the fluid will simply go through my closed mesh. 

Thanks so much :)